# Javascript Canvas DrawImage dissapears previus state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

my problem is when i use function drawImage() previus image on canvas has disappered. How i can rember previus state on my canvas?

I use react.

I try use save() and restore() but that not help me.

My code is:

```
updateCanvas(size, map, src) {
    var PSI = 256;
    var BSI = 16;
    var IZ = PSI;

    var  crop_canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');//this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
    console.log(crop_canvas);

    if(this.state.widthCanvas < size[0]) {
        this.setState({
            widthCanvas: size[0]
        });
    }

    var oiw = size[0];
    var iw = (oiw + PSI - 1) & ~(PSI - 1);
    var dmap = map;
    var pos_x = 0;
    var pos_y  =  this.state.heightCanvas;
    var myImage = [];
    var loadnumber = this.state.loadNumber;
    myImage[loadnumber] = new Image();

    this.setState({
        heightCanvas: this.state.heightCanvas+size[1]
    });

    myImage[loadnumber].src = src;
    myImage[loadnumber].onload = function(e){
        $.each(dmap, function(index, value){

            var cord = [];
            var y = (value / (iw / PSI)) | 0;
            var x = (value % (iw / PSI)) | 0;
            cord[0] = (x * PSI);
            cord[1] = (y * PSI);

            var cut_x = ((cord[0] * (2 * BSI + PSI) / PSI + BSI) * IZ / (PSI)) | 0;
            var cut_y = ((cord[1] * (2 * BSI + PSI) / PSI + BSI) * IZ / (PSI)) | 0;

            crop_canvas.drawImage(myImage[loadnumber] , cut_x, cut_y, PSI, PSI,  pos_x, pos_y, PSI, PSI);

            pos_x=pos_x+PSI;
            if(pos_x > oiw){
                pos_y=pos_y+PSI;
                pos_x = 0;
            }
        });
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            that.LoaderImage(parseInt(that.state.loadNumber)+1);
        },1000);
    }.bind(this);

}
```

Comment: The `drawImage()` function overwrites the canvas pixels. If you want to preserve what's there, you have to do it yourself by extracting the pixels and blending them with your image pixel by pixel.

Comment: I must draw all image again when i want add new image?

Comment: Drawing on a canvas pixel overwrites what was on the pixel previously. Now, your image can have an alpha channel that will cause it to be additively blended with previous content.

Comment: You have exmaple use this? I dont know how get previusly pixel.